# At what speed in air would a solid object turn to plasma?

Tags: thermodynamics, friction, projectile, drag, estimation

Just curious, friction can heat up what ever is moving.  The faster something moves the quicker it heats up. Is it possible in the perfect scenario to turn a speeding solid object to plasma through friction?  I'm thinking that the shock wave is different from the object, since the shock wave is essentially air. I believe the object would need substantially more heat to be changed into plasma.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43963/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43768/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/361104/25301

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What velocity must an aircraft achieve for its shock wave to transform to plasma?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43963/)

Comment: @Maxim note that the dupe you proposed is for the *shock wave* being a plasma state & not the object itself